# GoPro Studio Runtime Error

Tags: windows-8, gopro

Every time I try to run GoPro Studio I get 'Error Parsing c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framekwork\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config   Parser returned error 0xC00CE556'

Anyone know what is going on here? It's annoying and GoPro support didn't really have an answer. Aka there was an answer but no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my machine.config was bad. I found this great article and wanted to pass it along. Also fixed an issue when I was trying to install google chromecast.

http://blog.dragan-panjkov.com/archive/2012/08/19/troubleshooting-net-framework-parser-error-after-upgrade-to-windows-8.aspx